# Passing Query Parameter to Sub-Report

Tags: microsoft-access

It has been a long time since I have worked with MS Access and am not sure if I am doing this right.

I have a Report bound to a query of single list of user names.  The report groups on the user name and has a sub-report in the detail that is a chart.

The sub-report/chart is based on a query that accepts a parameter of the user name.  Since the sub report is not bound I need to pass the user name parameter from the main report detail onload event down to the sub-report and thus into the underlying query.

I am not understanding how to make that happen or even if my approach is sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this many times before.  It sounds like you have already created the first report.  Make the second subreport retrieve **all** the data you want and in the format you want.

Make a macro to call up the subreport.  In the macro set the where command to filter the recordset of the subreport.  In the picture below, with the where command...  The First =[PersonID]  links to the SQL query of the subreport.  The second part [Reports]![Main Report]![PersonID] will link to the main report text box titled 'PersonID'.

[image: Access 2010 Macro]

I typically put the macro in the Click event for the textbox in question.  So, in this case, when the user clicks on a Person's name, the macro is run (and since the cursor is on the record I want to retrieve) the proper parameter is passed to the where condition and effectively filtering my subreport.